# Why SSL certificate match with private key but doesn't match with CSR?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, csr

I use the following command to create your private key and CSR (using the ECC algorithm):

```
openssl ecparam -out ECC.key -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout
openssl req -new -key ECC.key -out ECC.csr -sha256 -subj "/C=VN/O=Custom Organization/OU=Custom Organizational Unit/CN=*.domain.tld"
```

After creating the CSR and the private key, I conducted a TLS certificate signed by Cloudflare to install on the original server.
But when I check the SSL certificate on this site: [Certificate Key Matcher](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html).

When I `Check if a Certificate and a Private Key match` use the certificate created by Cloudflare and the private key I created above, the result is: **The certificate and private key match!**

But when I `Check if a CSR and a Certificate match` use the Certificate created by CloudFlare and CSR that I created above, the result is: **The certificate and CSR do NOT match!**

Why happen this problem? Is Cloudflare CA didn't use the information in my CSR to build a certificate?

Comment: It's unclear to me at a glance what that tool is using to determine a match.  Perhaps https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/260203/can-any-field-in-a-csr-be-overwritten-in-the-issued-cert will help you.

Comment: @bartonjs Yes, exactly that Cloudflare CA has eliminated the entire information in CSR, the only thing they take to build a certificate is a public key.